# Flutter app performance with Admob ad banner

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, admob

I just wanted to ask you, if Google's Admob plugin in flutter doesnt affect app performance, because on my virtual device, it gets kind of laggy after I implement my ad banner.

They are updating automatically on the background and I dont know, if they are not stacked on top of each other or something like that.

Here is my code:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: "ca-app-pub-...");
    targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
      nonPersonalizedAds: false,
    );

    banner = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: "ca-app-pub-...",
      size: AdSize.banner,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print("BannerAd event is $event");
      },
    );

    banner
      ..load()
      ..show(
        anchorOffset: 0.0,
        horizontalCenterOffset: 10.0,
        anchorType: AnchorType.top,
      );

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    banner.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Facing the same issue

Comment: Having exact issue on my android devices, including on emulator and real device. Disabling the Ads will make the app much more smoother. 
For iOS this is happening too on emulator but it works perfectly fine and smooth on my real device (Iphone12). Looking forward for a way to fix it!

Comment: you can find the issue here: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/231

Comment: This is also happening with my real devices. 30 fps with admob banner, 60 fps without

Answer (score 0):

App performance getting low with AdMob
check this: [github](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/80)